# Haskell - combinations of lists and finding the maximum number of items

Tags: haskell

Suppose I have a list of lists that looks like this:

`ls = [[a, b, c, d, e], [a, b, c, d], [a, c, e]]`

where each list in this list of lists is of a custom data type (in terms of sorting lists this might matter so I'll just type it in):

`data Custom = Custom String Int`

I wanted to get all possible combinations of 1-3 lists in this list of lists, and find the combination that gives me the largest number of unique items. The output should be something like this (formatted for easier reading):

```
ms = [
[[a, b, c, d, e]], 
[[a, b, c, d]], 
[[a, c, e]], 
[[a, b, c, d, e], [a, b, c, d]], 
[[a, b, c, d, e], [a, c, e]],
[[a, b, c, d], [a, c, e]],
[[a, b, c, d, e], [a, b, c, d], [a, c, e]]
]
```

so that I can then map a function to count unique items in a list of lists to find the list of lists that gives me the maximum amount of unique items.

But when using these functions:

```
listOfListCombo :: Int -> [[a]] -> [[[a]]]
listOfListCombo _ [] = []
listOfListCombo n (x : xs) = map (x :) (listOfListCombo (n - 1) xs) ++ listOfListCombo n xs

combos :: [[Custom]] -> [[[Custom]]]
combos xs = (listOfListCombo 1 xs) ++ (listOfListCombo 2 xs) ++ (listOfListCombo 3 xs)
```

I always get an empty list when calling `combos xs`. Note that calling `listOfListCombo n xs` also gives me an empty list so I suspect the problem lies there.

How should I generate a list of lists of lists from a list of lists, so that I can use it to find the ideal combination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is already a builtin function for that: `Data.List.subsequences :: [a] -> [[a]]`. The implementation is pretty simple:

```
subsequences :: [a] -> [[a]]
subsequences xs = [] : nonEmptySubsequences xs

nonEmptySubsequences :: [a] -> [[a]]
nonEmptySubsequences [] = []
nonEmptySubsequences (x:xs) =
   [x] : foldr (\ys r -> ys : (x : ys) : r) [] (nonEmptySubsequences xs)
```

---

But if you wanna show off your monad-monkey spirit you can always do `filterM (const [True, False])`

Comment: I also imported ```Data.List``` so I guess I can go with ```subsequences```. Thank you.

Comment: If this solved your issue, you can mark it as solved